# SQL select left join to filter multiple condition on the same tablhe

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join

I am having hard time in the best practice to filter out a select state. I have a scalar function that works with this select query

I only want to return just a LIST of IRId's

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.IRId  
    FROM cmp.NPTable NP
INNER JOIN IPTable IP ON IP.IPtId = NP.IPd
LEFT JOIN  IPCTable IPC ON IPC.IPId = NP.IPId AND IPC.IsNC= 1 
WHERE NP.PCN Id = @PCNId  
    AND fGetCount(IP.IPId) = 0
```

This works but I know using a scalar function within the WHERE clause is bad practice.

The query in the `fGetCount` is

```
SELECT 
    @Result = 
        Count(*)
FROM IPCTable
WHERE IsCopy = 1 and IPId = @IPId
```

Without using the function in the where clause what is the best way to merge both queries which is referencing the same table, IPCTable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS()` should work in the place of your function:

```
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
               FROM IPCTable IPC
               WHERE IPC.IPId = IP.IPId
               AND IPC.IsCopy = 1)
```

You can also remove the join to `IPCTable` since you aren't selecting from it and as a `LEFT JOIN` it wasn't filtering results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.IRId  
FROM cmp.NPTable NP
INNER JOIN IPTable IP ON IP.IPtId = NP.IPd 
WHERE NP.PCN Id = @PCNId  
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM IPCTable IPC
                WHERE IPC.IPId = IP.IPId
                AND IPC.IsCopy = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you don't want the data which is having `IsCopy = 1` in the table `IPCTable`. Since you already have the table in the `left join` you can update the same in the where condition.

```
SELECT DISTINCT IP.IRId  
    FROM cmp.NPTable NP
INNER JOIN IPTable IP ON IP.IPtId = NP.IPd
LEFT JOIN  IPCTable IPC ON IPC.IPId = NP.IPId AND IPC.IsNC= 1 
WHERE NP.PCN Id = @PCNId AND IPC.IsCopy = 0
```